# What is the difference between NULL and __null in C++?

Tags: c++, null, keyword

I have the following code:

```
MyType x = NULL;
```

NetBeans gave me a suggestion to change it to this:

```
MyType x = __null;
```

I looked it up and found that `__null` is called a "compiler keyword", which I assumed to mean it's used internally for the compiler. I don't understand why NetBeans suggested to change it to a compiler keyword.

What's the difference between `NULL` and `__null` in c++?

Comment: In C++11 and after you should use the keyword nullptr.

Comment: Don't use `__null`. If it's an implementation detail, it's not portable to use it. If it's defined by the project, it's using a name reserved for use by the implementation, it's not legal to use that identifier and it should be removed from the project.

Comment: If you want `NULL` use `nullptr`. If that doesn't compile then you don't have a pointer and you are doing the wrong thing.

Comment: You want `nullptr` - always.

Comment: Strange suggestion from NetBeans there. Possibly worth raising this with its devs, though we can't tell for sure with the slim pickings of information provided.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`__null` is a `g++` internal thing that serves roughly the same purpose as the standard `nullptr` added in C++11 (acting consistently as a pointer, never an integer).

`NULL` is defined as `0`, which can be implicitly used as integer, boolean, floating point value or pointer, which is a problem when it comes to overload resolution, when you want to call the function that takes a pointer specifically.

In any event, you shouldn't use `__null` because it's a `g++` implementation detail, so using it guarantees non-portable code. If you can rely on C++11 (surely you can by now?), use `nullptr`. If not, `NULL` is your only portable option.

Comment: Note that `NULL` does not have to be defined as `0`. It's whatever the implementation chooses as a null-pointer constant.

Comment: @PeteBecker: True. It's just that pre-C++11, I don't know of any systems that didn't use `0`. In the C++11 era, they're allowed to make it evaluate to `nullptr`, but I'm not sure which compilers, if any, have pulled that particular trigger (since it could conceivably break existing code).

Comment: @PeteBecker I think there's some confusion here between `0` as the address of the pointer, and the literal `0` in source code. The latter is defined as yielding a null pointer when it is assigned to a pointer, even though the resulting address is implementation defined.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `NULL` is sometimes defined as `0`, sometimes as `(void *) 0`, depending on the compiler.

Comment: @DavidConrad — `0` is a valid null pointer constant. `NULL` is a macro that is required to expand to a valid null pointer constant. `NULL` is not required to expand to `0`. There are other (implementation-specific) ways to write a null pointer constant. The value of a pointer that has been set to null is not implementation defined it is unspecified. “Implementation defined” means that a conforming implementation must document its behavior.

Comment: @DavidConrad — `(void*)0` is a valid null pointer constant in C but **not** in C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker I wasn't saying that `NULL` was *required* to expand to `0`, only that that is one possibility, but thank you for the other information.

Answer (score 12):

`NULL` has been overtaken from C into C++ and - prior to C++11 - adopted its C meaning:

> until C++11: The macro NULL is an implementation-defined null pointer
>   constant, which may be an integral constant expression rvalue of
>   integer type that evaluates to zero.

C++11 then introduced a dedicated null pointer literal `nullptr` of type `std::nullptr_t`. But - probably for backward compatibility - the macro `NULL` was not removed; its definition  was just a bit relaxed in that compilers may now define it either as integral or as pointer type:

> C++11 onwards: an integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of
>   type std::nullptr_t

If you use `NULL`, then you get implementation-defined behaviour in overload resolution. Consider, for example, the following code with a compiler that uses the integral-version of `NULL`-macro. Then a call using `NULL` as parameter passed to a function may lead to ambiguities:

```
struct SomeOverload {

    SomeOverload(int x) {
        cout << "taking int param: " << x << endl;
    }
    SomeOverload(void* x) {
        cout << "taking void* param: " << x << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    int someVal = 10;

    SomeOverload a(0);
    SomeOverload b(&someVal);

    // SomeOverload c(NULL);  // Call to constructor is ambiuous
    SomeOverload d(nullptr);
}
```

So it is recommended to use `nullptr` where ever you want to express pointer type.

And don't use `__null`, as this is a compiler-specific, non-portable constant; `nullptr`, in contrast, is perfectly portable.

Answer (score 8):

`NULL` is the old C symbol for a null pointer. C++ traditionally have used `0` for null pointers, and since the C++11 standard `nullptr`.

Considering that `x` doesn't seem to be a pointer then you can't initialize `x` to be a null pointer, and the `__null` symbol is perhaps some compiler-internal symbol for a null *value* (which is a concept that doesn't really exist in standard C++).

If you want `x` to initialized to some default state, then you have to rely on the `MyClass` default constructor to initialize the objects and its member variables to some suitable default values.